# How to write to and read from JSON file at the same time

Tags: python, json

I have a physics simulation python code that calculates room temperature and I want to plot the data as it happens at each time step.

At each timestamp a module writes the data to a json file and another module reads this file every timestep and tries to plot it on.

The problem is, as I see it, the synchronisation of the two modules. Is there a way to do this? I thought of a write lock on the file but that helps only reading it. Writing should happen continuously, but I do not mind if reading is prevented while writing happens. Please help.

Comment: My advice would be to not use json. JSON is not really suitable for rapidly updating streaming data. Instead consider something like CSV that allows continuously adding data to the end without changing the file structure.

Comment: Thanks Mousetail. The issue is reading the file without preventing write. How does the use of CSV file help? Can you point me at an example that helps with this? Cheers

Comment: The advantage of CSV is that new data is written at the end, so if the reading process just keeps trying to read new data from the end it will get the new data as soon as it is available

Comment: I think I am missing something here. I thought the problem is the file being in accessible for writing while it is being read. Are u saying csv allows reading and writing simultaneously?

Comment: Every file allows this (unless you explicitly lock it when opening), this does not depend on the file type